# multi case selection in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

```
SELECT image_id, 
       CASE image_id 
         WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT image_path 
                      FROM   images 
                      WHERE  image_id IN (SELECT default_image 
                                          FROM   registration 
                                          WHERE  reg_id IN (SELECT favorite_id 
                                                            FROM   @favDT))) 
         ELSE (SELECT image_path 
               FROM   images 
               WHERE  image_id = b.image_id 
                      AND active = 1) 
       END AS image_path 
FROM   buddies b 
WHERE  reg_id IN (SELECT favorite_id 
                  FROM   @favDT)
```

i'm facing a problem in this query because the `select favorite_id from @favDT` returns many favorite id in the case but i need to get the same favorite id that is selected in the from section `FROM buddies b where reg_id in (select favorite_id from @favDT)` and use it the `case when 0`

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT image_id, 
       CASE image_id 
         WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT image_path 
                      FROM   images 
                      WHERE  image_id IN (SELECT default_image 
                                          FROM   registration 
                                          WHERE  reg_id IN (SELECT favorite_id 
                                                            FROM   @favDT
                                                            WHERE favorite_id = b.reg_id
                                                           )
                                         )
                     ) 
         ELSE (SELECT image_path 
               FROM   images 
               WHERE  image_id = b.image_id 
                      AND active = 1) 
       END AS image_path 
FROM   buddies b 
WHERE  reg_id IN (SELECT favorite_id 
                  FROM   @favDT)
```

Comment: how can i add a case if there are no rows selected?

Comment: no row selected from images? and which image_path you want in that case?

Comment: no rows selected in buddies in that case in need the same operation when image_id is 0

Comment: but in that case you will get all the images from table images which are not associated to any buffies with reg_id in @favDT. In that case you can add after my query `UNION ALL SELECT image_id, image_path FROM images WHERE IMAGE_ID NOT IN (SELECT default_image FROM registration WHERE reg_id IN (SELECT favorite_id FROM @favDT WHERE favorite_id = b.reg_id))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to write condition like below :

```
SELECT image_id, 
       CASE image_id 
         WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT image_path 
                      FROM   images 
                      WHERE  image_id IN (SELECT default_image 
                                          FROM   registration 
                                          WHERE  reg_id  = b.reg_id)) 
         ELSE (SELECT image_path 
               FROM   images 
               WHERE  image_id = b.image_id 
                      AND active = 1) 
       END AS image_path 
FROM   buddies b 
WHERE  reg_id IN (SELECT favorite_id 
                  FROM   @favDT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this without CASE:

```
SELECT b.image_id,
       im.image_path as image_path
FROM buddies b 
JOIN @favDT fdt on b.reg_id=fdt.favorite_id
JOIN images im on (b.image_id<>0 and b.image_id=im.image_id and active=1) 
                  OR
                  (b.image_id=0 and r.default_image=im.image_id)

LEFT JOIN registration r on (b.image_id=0 and fdt.favorite_id=r.reg_id)
```